# What's the earliest point in time I can access xml-defined subviews in a custom view

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view, android-inflate

I have this xml file:

```
<my.CustomView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ff0000"/>
</my.CustomView>
```

And this corresponding class:

```
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout {

    private View mSubview;

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mSubview = getChildAt(0);
    }
}
```

In the constructor the first child should be assigned to mSubview. However it's null. It works when I access the first child later, for instance, when I click a button. At which point can I access my custom view's subviews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should read the docs more carefully...

> View.onFinishInflate()

is what I was looking for.